# Minkowski sum and Polygons

Tags: geometry, convex-analysis, computational-geometry, polygons, convex-geometry

*The problem*:..

Given two convex polygons $A$ and $B$, we can define Minkowski sum as A + B = {a + b: a $\in$ A, b $\in$ B}, where $a + b$ vector sum. Prove that:

> every vertex $p \in A + B$ is a Minkowski sum of vertices of $A$ and $B$

Hint: Use the *external perpendicular to $u$*.

---

*My attemp*t:

We could use that lemma:

> for *every* external perpendicular u to an edge of A, there *exists* an external perpendicular to an edge of A + B, which will be parallel to u.

which I proved in another time.

Comment: If you parametrize the boundary of $A$ & $B$ by vector functions $a(t),b(t)$ for $t\in[0,1]$ with suitable periodicity constraints on the functions and their first derivatives such as $a(0)=a(1),a'(0)=a'(1)$, wouldn't it be the case that vertices of $A$ & $B$ would be discontinuities in $a'$ and $b'$? Do you think that might help at all? Alternatively, can you use the fact that taking convex hulls and taking Minkowski sums are commutative operations (and therefore the order of them can be reversed)?

Comment: To be honest @bgins, I am not sure how this will help. :/

Comment: Using the hint, let two adjacent edges $e,f$ of $A$ which meet at vertex $a$ have external perpendiculars $u,v$ (which are obviously not parallel; this would correspond to a discontinuity of the tangent to the perimeter in my previous suggestion, which ignores the hint you are given). Now use the lemma on these two edges and their external perpendiculars $u$ & $v$. All that remains is to argue that the corresponding edges in $A+B$ meet at a vertex. But wouldn't that have to be true if the images of $e$ & $f$ are connected and the corresponding external perpendiculars change from $u$ to $v$?

Comment: Yeah @bgins that makes sense!!! Are you going to post an answer, or should I delete the question? I prefer the first, is you ask me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the hint, let two adjacent edges $e,f$ of $A$ which meet at vertex $a$ have external perpendiculars $u,v$ (which are obviously not parallel; this would correspond to a discontinuity of the tangent to the perimeter in my previous suggestion, which ignores the hint you are given). Now use the lemma on these two edges and their external perpendiculars $u$ & $v$. All that remains is to argue that the corresponding edges in $A+B$ meet at a vertex. But wouldn't that have to be true if the images of $e$ & $f$ are connected and the corresponding external perpendiculars change from $u$ to $v$?